# Programming interview questions I had: Reverse a string and find the mode of an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I had a C++ programming test for a big tech company which shall not be named. I was given the following chunks of code and asked to use them to reverse a string and return the mode of an array.

```
char * reverse(char * str, int n)
{
   ...
}
```

and

```
int mode(int * arr, int n)
{
   ...
}
```

I'm not sure if I did them the "best" way, but I'm curious how the high priests of Stack Overflow would do them. I'm also curious why they gave me such a strange prototype in the first case. Wouldn't it be better as a void function? And shouldn't they have given my `size_t` for `n` in both cases?

I wrote

```
for (char* i(str), j(str+n); i < j; ++i, --j)
    std::swap(*i, *j)
return str;
```

and

```
if (n == 0)
    throw("Can't have the mode of an empty array, bro.")
std::map<int,int> cntMap;
std::pair<int,int> top(arr[0], 1);
cntMap.insert(top);
for (int k(1); k < n; ++k)
{
    if (cntMap.count(*k) == 0)
       cntMap.insert(*k, 1);
    else
       ++cntMap[*k];
    if (cntMap[*k] > top.second)
       top = std::make_pair(*k, cntMap[*k])
     return top.first;       
}
```

Did I fail?

Comment: Does it work? Did you test all the corner cases?

Comment: My first question for the mode of an array would be to ask "is it sorted"?

Comment: This was a test I took online and had very limited time to do.

Comment: In `reverse`, the type of `i` and `j` is wrong (looks like you intended for them to be pointers)  And you are dereferencing the element beyond the end.

Comment: Not a fan of your for loop, why are you casting a `char*` to an `int`? Plus `j` initially points to the `\0` which you swap to the first position, effectively making a null string (assuming it's a c-string and not just an array of characters, in which case you reference past the end)...

Comment: So wait, did you write it with `int` or with `char*`?

Comment: What is the *mode* of an array ?

Comment: @hivert: *mean*, *median*, and *mode* are elementary statistics

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I know about mean median and standard deviation but I've never heard about the mode. Note that I never learn't statistic in English since I'm french. So I learnt a new English word today ! Thanks.

Comment: This is the first time I have ever seen an interview question asking for the mode of an integer array.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. Post on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, does the string have a null terminator? Ignoring the issue raised by [hivert](/questions/tagged/hivert) for a moment (though, a highly valid issue it is), swapping first array value and last array value would put the null character at the start of the string, which to most string-printing functions, tells them "there's no string here".

Also, were you ensured that (n - 1) = string length, or just array size? If the string length was shorter than (n - 1), then there would be garbage data past the null terminator...which you'd proceed to swap to the front of the string, causing most string-printing functions to print the garbage data, then stop before the "good" reversed string even showed up.

So, you'd want to do something along the lines of:

```
char * reverse(char * str, int n)
{
   // Sanity check, if the string starts with null terminator, 
   // there's nothing in the string.
   if(str[0] = NULL)
   {
       return str;
   }
   size_t i, j = 0;
   // While you aren't at the end of the array and
   // while the next character is not null (0x00)
   while((i < n) && (str[i+1] != NULL))
   {
       i++; // Found another good character
   }
   // You're going to process the array from both ends. 
   // i tells you the end, j the front.
   while(j < i)
   {
       // Leaves the null terminator alone.
       swap(str[i], str[j]);
       i--;
       j++;
   }
return str;
}
```

Edit: realized that my posted code had bugs of its own. Hurray for corner cases.

Answer (score 4):

The first for loop is clearly wrong at least for two reasons: The type of `i` and `j`, and the index of the last element of the array which should be `str+n-1`

```
for (char *i = str, *j = str+n-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    std::swap(*i, *j)
return str;
```

Comment: Mode is the value that appears most often in the data

Comment: Is it standard English ? I've never heard of it (I'm not a native English speaker).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it's standard (and elementary) statistics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). It's certainly not used as often as `mean` or `median` though, at least in my experience..

Answer (score 4):

Your second code is overly complicated.

You just need:

```
++cntMap[*k];
```

And you would just need to keep track of the 'k' value of the highest count, no need to make it a pair.

Second, your `return top.first;` before the loop has finished, which is clearly not what you want.

You are using an `int k`, and then using `*k`, which clearly won't compile. This also applies to `*i` and `*j` in your `reverse` function. You seem to be mixing up integer indices and iterators...